# Strong law of large numbers for i.i.d. random variables with distribution depending on $n$

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $X_1^{(n)}, X_2^{(n)}...$ are independent and identically distributed random variable with zero mean and $E[|X_1^{(n)}|]<\infty$ for each $n$. Are these conditions sufficient to ensure 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{(n)} \to 0
$$ 
almost surely (or in probability)?

If I understand correctly, if we additionally knew that $var(X_1^{(n)})<\infty$ then we could apply Kolmogrov's variance criterion and deduce almost sure convergence.

Comment: No it's not.  You need the variances to be bounded for all n.

Comment: Counter example: Suppose $X_i^{(n)}$ all have the same distribution $\mathbb{P}(X_i^{(n)}=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_i^{(n)}=-1)=1/2$.  Then for $n$ odd, $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{(n)}\geq 1)=1/2$.